# Troubleshoot bacteria fixation for SEM

Tags: bacteriology

I fixate bacteria on titanium coins for 1 h i 2.5 % Gluaraldehyde. Then wash 3 times in ddH2O. Then 10 min in each solution of Ethanol 10 %, 30 %, 50 %, 70 % 90%, 100%. Finally soaking in HMDS in 15 min, then take out the HMDS and let dry overnight. Sputtercoat with Ag/Pd. I know I have bacteria on the titanium surface from the beginning but I dont see anything in SEM. What am I doing wrong?